# jQuery seems to not split

Tags: jquery, split

I am using the following code that contains a call to `split` a list of ids.

```
$("#editlisting").live('click', function(event) {
    //alert("hello");
    editlistingid = $("tbody td.small input:checkbox:checked").map(function(i, el) {
        return $(el).attr("id"); 
    }).get();
    eid = editlistingid.split(",");
    alert(eid[0]);
    editlead();
});
```

However, what I am finding is that it is not getting split at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`editlistingid` will hold an `Array`, as the result of `get()` was assigned to it.

> Without a parameter, `.get()` returns all of the elements:
>
> ```
> alert($('li').get());
> ```
>
> All of the matched DOM nodes are returned by this call, **contained in a
>   standard array**.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/get/).

`split()` works on a `String`.

> Splits a **`String`** object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

You are trying to call a `String` method on an `Array`. That won't work.

It looks like you could use `editlistingid` directly.